# "Fatal error:Class DrupalDefaultEntityController not found " error is showing after upgrading to 7

Tags: 7, upgrading

We have upgraded from 6.13 to 7.41, and we are getting the following error after upgrading:

> Fatal error:Class ' DrupalDefaultEntityController ' not found

The site runs on PHP 5.3, Apache 2, and MySQL 5.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you sure you uploaded all the files? That class is defined in includes/entities.inc.

Comment: yes i have uploaded all the files.